# How to update image fields using Django forms

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create a blogging application and  in it I have 2 forms, one for editing pre-existing posts, and the other for creating them. However, I am unable to get updated images, when the edit form is submitted. All textual data goes through...

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= 'blog_posts')
    short_description = models.TextField()
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status, default=0)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'coverimages', null =True, blank = True)
    captioned_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'captionedimages', null=True, blank = True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    featured = models.IntegerField(choices=Featured, default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey(PostCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    embedded_code = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='null')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py:

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Post Title')
    short_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":3, "cols":100}))
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
    status = forms.NullBooleanField(label='Ready to Publish?')
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Select a cover image:', required=False)
    captioned_image = forms.ImageField(label='Select a captionable image:', required=False)
    caption = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    try:
        category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=PostCategory.objects.all())
    except:
        category = forms.ChoiceField(choices= ('default'))
    embed = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":3, "cols":100}))
    tags = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs = {"rows":1, "cols":150}))
```

editpost.html:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.media }}
        <legend>Edit Post: {{ post }}</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Title</label>
          {% render_field form.title class="form-control" %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label mt-4" for="exampleTextarea"
            >Short Description</label
          >
          {% render_field form.short_description class="form-control" %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Content</label>
          {{ form.content }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label mt-4" for="exampleSelect1"
            >Ready To Publish?</label
          >
          {% render_field form.status class="form-select" id="exampleSelect1"%}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label mt-4" for="formFile">Cover Image</label>
          {% render_field form.image class="form-control" id="formFile"%}
          {% if post %}
          <br>
          <p>Current Image:</p>
          <img src="{{ post.cover_image.url }}" alt="" style="height: 400px;">
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label mt-4" for="formFile"
              >Captioned Image</label
            >
            {% render_field form.captioned_image class="form-control" %}
            {% if post %}
            <br>
            <p>Current Image:</p>
            <img src="{{ post.captioned_image.url }}" alt="" style="height: 400px;">
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault"
              >Caption</label
            >
            {% render_field form.caption class="form-control" %}
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Category</label>
          {% render_field form.category class="form-select"%}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Embed</label>
          {% render_field form.embed class="form-control"%}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Tags</label>
          {% render_field form.tags class="form-control"%}
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

After the form is submitted, the image is not saved in the media/coverimages folder, and the development server returns:

```
Not Found: /media/images.jpg
[23/Jan/2022 09:16:24] "GET /media/images.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3786
```

One thing I have noticed is that if I use the admin site, the image uploads properly, which leads me to believe that perhaps issue is with the form, or how the form is being handled

EDIT:

views.py:

```
# Converts tag string from a form to a nice iterable list
def tagsplitter(input):
    input = str(input)
    tags = input.split(', ')
    return tags


# Fetches all the tags of a QueryObject and returns tags in a nice list
def tagstringer(object):
    tags = object.tags.all()
    taglist = []
    for tag in tags:
        taglist.append(tag.tag)
    str1 = ", "
    return str1.join(taglist)

@staff_member_required(login_url='login')
def edit_post(request, slug):
    context = {}
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context.update({'post': post})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image_path = post.cover_image.path
            if os.path.exists(image_path):
                os.remove(image_path)
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            short_description = request.POST.get('short_description')
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            statusraw = request.POST.get('status')
            if str(statusraw) == 'true':
                status = 1
            else:
                status = 0
            cover_image = request.FILES.get('image')
            captioned_image = request.FILES.get('captioned_image')
            caption = request.POST.get('caption')
            category = request.POST.get('category')
            tags = tagsplitter(request.POST.get('tags'))
            embed = request.POST.get('embed')
            print(f"cover image: {cover_image}")
            if cover_image is not None:
                if captioned_image is not None:
                    # Add both images
                    newpost = Post.objects.filter(pk=post.pk).update(title=title, cover_image = cover_image, captioned_image=captioned_image, short_description=short_description, content=content, status=status, caption=caption, category=category, embedded_code=embed)
                else:
                    print('Adding cover image only')
                    # Add only cover image
                    newpost = Post.objects.filter(pk=post.pk).update(title=title, cover_image = cover_image, short_description=short_description, content=content, status=status, caption=caption, category=category, embedded_code=embed)
            else:
                if captioned_image is not None:
                    # Add only captioned image
                    newpost = Post.objects.filter(pk=post.pk).update(title=title, captioned_image=captioned_image, short_description=short_description, content=content, status=status, caption=caption, category=category, embedded_code=embed)
                else:
                    # Add neither
                    newpost = Post.objects.filter(pk=post.pk).update(title=title, short_description=short_description, content=content, status=status, caption=caption, category=category, embedded_code=embed)
            newpost = Post.objects.get(title = title)
            newpost.tags.clear()
            for tag in tags:
                tag = Tag.objects.update_or_create(tag = tag)
                newpost.tags.add(tag[0])
            return redirect('blogger:post', slug = slug)

    else:
        tagstr = tagstringer(post)
        init_dict  = {
            'title': post.title,
            'content': post.content,
            'short_description': post.short_description,
            'status': post.status,
            'cover_image': post.cover_image,
            'caption': post.caption,
            'embed': post.embedded_code,
            'category':post.category,
            'tags': tagstr
            }
        form = EditForm(initial = init_dict)
        context.update({'form': form})
    return render(request, template_name="blogger/edit_post.html", context=context)
```

Comment: Can you share views.py too?

Comment: @FirdavsbekNarzullaev I have edited the original post with views.py